# Jekyll customizing default theme

Tags: html, jekyll, github-pages

I'm building my first website using Jekyll and I quite like the default minima theme. However, I would like to change some things about theme like background color or stuff like that...how would I do that?

I tried changing the CSS file in the /_site/assets folder, but even though it does change the file and the webiste looks different with the Jekyll preview, it doesn't change it permanently because I guess it's not building the website with a new CSS file.

My directory structure is like this:

```
├── 404.html
├── about.md
├── assets
│   └── js
│       └── main.js
├── _config.yml
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── index.md
├── _posts
│   ├── 2018-02-25-animosity.md
│   ├── 2018-02-25-test.html
│   └── main.js
└── _site
    ├── 404.html
    ├── about
    │   └── index.html
    ├── assets
    │   ├── js
    │   │   └── main.js
    │   ├── main.css
    │   └── minima-social-icons.svg
    ├── feed.xml
    ├── index.html
    └── jekyll
        └── update
            └── 2018
                └── 02
                    └── 25
                        ├── animosity.html
                        └── test.html
```

Comment: If you start with Jekyll I would STRONGLY advice you to NOT use the default theme. Remove it. Jekyll is very simple. Too much 'magic', while Jekyll should be all about NO magic: https://jekyllrb.com/philosophy#1-no-magic

Answer (score 2):

You said in a deleted answer that you are using the Minima theme as a gem.

In this case, it's possible to "override" single files by creating a modified copy of them in the right place in your folder structure.

See the Jekyll docs:
[Overriding theme defaults](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/#overriding-theme-defaults)

For example, to override `main.css` (shown in your directory structure under `_site/assets/main.css`, you would need to create a copy of that file here:

```
├── 404.html
├── about.md
├── assets
│   ├── js
│   │   └── main.js
│   └── main.css                 <-- HERE
├── _config.yml
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── index.md
├── _posts
│   ├── 2018-02-25-animosity.md
│   ├── 2018-02-25-test.html
│   └── main.js
└── _site
    ├── ...                      <-- NOT HERE
```

**Note: Do NOT change anything in the `_site` directory, because that will be deleted and re-created each time you build your page!**
Any template changes have to be made in the main directory.

Comment: that is what i tried to do but it seems like gh-pages completely brakes if i do that and it doesnt give any error i can work with :(

Comment: Can I keep those overriding files in different subdirectory, in that case how to specify the path in _config.yml file ?